# writing data to file with multithredding python

Tags: python, multithreading

i am calling a function vision to process images, i want to process a huge amount of images and write the data to file. i am using multithreading and running 4 threads and passing a different list of imagename to each thread but when i write the data to file it is overwriting and showing result of only one thread.
how can process these images faster and write the data of coming from function in a file.
this is my vision function.

```
def vision(filelist):
    from google.cloud import vision
    from google.cloud.vision import types
    os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = r'Logo Detection-ecc10ae26b70.json'
    global lck
    global df
    global dff
    lck.acquire()
    for i in range(len(onlyfiles)):
        imagepath=batch_folder+"\\"+onlyfiles[i]
        with io.open(onlyfiles[i], 'rb') as image_file:
            content = image_file.read()
            logolist=[]
            labellist=[]
            objectlist=[]
            image = vision.types.Image(content=content)
            response = client.logo_detection(image=image)
            logos = response.logo_annotations
            response = client.label_detection(image=image)
            labels = response.label_annotations
            objects = client.object_localization(image=image).localized_object_annotations

            for logo in logos:
                logolist.append(logo.description)
            for label in labels:
                labellist.append(label.description)
            for obj in objects:
                objectlist.append(obj.name)
            logolist2.append(logolist)
            labellist2.append(labellist)
            objectlist2.append(objectlist)
            dff=[]  
            lck.acquire()
            dff = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(onlyfiles,logolist2,labellist2,objectlist2)),columns =['filename', 'logo','label','object'])
            df.append(dff,ignore_index=True)
            lck.release()


    df.to_csv(csvadd, index=False) 

############image reading and divding data for threads#################
batch_folder='D:\\Projects\\VAT\\fakedetection\\keyframe\\ffmpeg-4.2.1-win64-static\\video'
onlyfiles = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(batch_folder), '*.jpg') 
countofimage=len(onlyfiles)
division=int(countofimage/4)
index1=[0,division]
index2=[division+1,division+division]
index3=[division+division+1,division+division+division]
index4=[division+division+division+1,division+division+division+division]
threadfile1=onlyfiles[index1[0]:index1[1]]
threadfile2=onlyfiles[index2[0]:index2[1]]
threadfile3=onlyfiles[index3[0]:index3[1]]
threadfile4=onlyfiles[index4[0]:index4[1]]   

t1 = threading.Thread(target=vision, args=(threadfile1,)) 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=vision, args=(threadfile2,)) 
t3 = threading.Thread(target=vision, args=(threadfile3,)) 
t4 = threading.Thread(target=vision, args=(threadfile4,)) 

# starting thread 1 
t1.start() 
# starting thread 2 
t2.start() 
t3.start()
t4.start()

# wait until thread 1 is completely executed 
t1.join() 
# wait until thread 2 is completely executed 
t2.join() 
t3.join()
t4.join()
# both threads completely executed 
print("Done!")
```

i tired lock and global df but the output is not coming from all threads in the file.if there is any improvement needed for this code which can process faster please suggest and help to write data coming from threads to a file
the code is working fine no error. i am just not just getting proper output

Answer (score 1):

Working on files concurrently is a standard problem in multithreading. If not handled correctly, things like lost update problems will arise like it does in yor case.

Using locks is one approach to ensure that all updates will appear in the file. However, if you use a lock, other threads will have to wait until the lock is released before they can write to the file. Depending on the duration of the locking per thread the program could end up performing like a single thread application in the worst case.

My approach to solve your problem does not depend on locks at all: Would it be possible for you to write the outputs of the different threads to different files first and merge the output files afterwards? This way, you won't have to worry about lost updates.